# Spring SOAP How to remove "lang=en" attribute from <faultstring> in SOAPExceptionResponse?

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap

I have a solution that configure "detail" body of SOAP Exception response:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MyException", propOrder = {
    "causeMessage",
    "details",
    "MyStatusCode",
    "proprietarySystemStatusCode"
})
```

I assign value in runtime.

Here it is my response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">Operation not supported</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns2:fault xmlns:ns2="mylink">
               <ns2:causeMessage>Operation not supported</ns2:causeMessage>
               <ns2:details>mydetail</ns2:details>
               <ns2:MyStatusCode>002</ns2:MyStatusCode>
               <ns2:proprietarySystemStatusCode/>
            </ns2:fault>
         </detail>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I **have to** remove xml:lang="en" attribute from faultstring to validate this response in client side, but
I don't understand how to do it at all. Client can't parse/remove attribute by itself, so I should to remove it from server response.

Any ideas?

My app use spring soap instruments such as SoapFaultDefinition and SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver, but I didn't find any methods, that can help me with my problem.